# Server with multiple clients - writing with select()

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a server that handles multiple clients at a time. Apparently I'm supposed to use `select`. I've found numerous tutorials but none of them handle writing.

I get how I'm supposed to read data in, but what's the.. appropriate way to handle writing back to the clients in my 'loop'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have data that you want to send to a particular socket, then you need select() to return when there is space available in that socket's output-buffer.  The way to tell select() to do that is similar to using select() just for read -- except that also you do the FD_SET on the second fd_set object.

```
int socks[10] = {... some client sockets...}

while(1)
{
   fd_set readSet, writeSet;

   FD_ZERO(&readSet);
   FD_ZERO(&writeSet);

   int maxSock = -1;
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      FD_SET(socks[i], &readSet);
      if (socks[i] > maxSock) maxSock = socks[i];

      if (IHaveDataToSendToThisSocket(i))  // implement this function as appropriate to your program
      {
         FD_SET(socks[i], &writeSet);
         if (socks[i] > maxSock) maxSock = socks[i];
      }
   }

   int ret = select(maxSock+1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, NULL);
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      perror("select() failed");
      break;
   }

   // Do I/O for sockets that are ready
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      if (FD_ISSET(socks[i], &readSet))
      {
         // there is data to read on this socket, so call recv() on it
      }

      if (FD_ISSET(socks[i], &writeSet))
      {
         // this socket has space available to write data to, so call send() on it
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The part I'm confused about is, with reading, all I have to do is (a) wait for data and (b) read it in. With writing, how can I tell if I have data to be written? Am I supposed to store it in like a global vector or something?

Comment: I need to write back to the client based on what is sent to me. By the time I'm signaled telling me I can write again, how will I be able to access my read data?

Comment: Whether or not you have data that you want to write to the socket depends on what your application does.  For your case:  if you want to have your server respond to received data by sending some other data back on the same socket, then for each socket you should have some data structure that represents the "state of the conversation" for that socket.

Comment: For example, if you know your server's responses will always be less than 100 bytes, your could have (for each socket) an array of 100 chars, an integer representing an offset into this array (set to zero) and an integer representing number-of-valid-bytes in the array (also set to zero). Then when you get some data from a socket, you'd place your response bytes into the socket's array, and set the number-of-valid-bytes integer for that socket to the number of bytes you placed.  Implement IHaveDataToSendToThisSocket() to return true iff the offset-integer is less than the number-of-valid-bytes.

Comment: ... lastly, when FD_ISSET(socks[i], &writeSet) returns true, you'd send() as many remaining valid bytes from the buffer as you can, and increment the offset by the number of bytes you sent.  When the offset value equals the number-of-valid-bytes value, you know you've sent the entire response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6268/discussion-between-jonathan-lingle-and-jeremy-friesner)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you want to use poll() rather than select() but this is besides the point. To write to multiple clients you want to make sure that you don't use blocking writes. You might get away with not detecting whether a particular can digest more data and thus you might not need to use poll() (or select()) when writing. However, if you want to be prepared for clients consuming data with different speed you might want to receive notifications when a client can digest more data.

Other than that, poll() or select() can notify on both data available in the read buffer or space available in the write buffer. The use is pretty much the same except that you need to set a different flag.