# Client console to display received messages and accept messages

Tags: c++, loops, client, client-server, client-side

I have a server-multiple-client program. The server needs to (and can) send messages to the client at any time, so the client needs to be continually ready to receive (and display on its console) all messages that the server sends.

At the same time, the client console needs to accept inputs to be sent to the server for processing (the server serves as the intermediary between clients).

How can I do this? I am working with a piece of code taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7785/Single-Server-With-Multiple-Clients-a-Simple-C-Imp and the client code (which I am attaching below) works by accepting a message from the server, sending that to the server, before it is ready to receive messages. How do I adapt this to do what I need?

I am only including the main body of the client code because I think it might just be a matter of using loops - though I can't figure what loops - so please let me know if I should attach any other code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mySocket.h"
#include "myLog.h"
#include "myException.h"
#include "myHostInfo.h"

myLog winLog;
void readServerConfig(string&);
void checkFileExistence(const string&);

int main()
{
//initialize the winsock library
myTcpSocket::initialize();

//get client's information (assume neither the name nor the address is given)
winLog << endl;
winLog << "retrieve the localHost [CLIENT] name and address:" << endl;
myHostInfo clientInfo;
string clientName = clientInfo.getHostName();
string clientIPAddress = clientInfo.getHostIPAddress();
cout << "name: " << clientName << endl;
cout << "address: " << clientIPAddress << endl;
winLog << "     ==> name: " << clientName << endl;
winLog << "     ==> address: " << clientIPAddress << endl;

//get server's IP address and name
string serverIPAddress = "";
readServerConfig(serverIPAddress);
winLog << endl;
winLog << "retrieve the remoteHost [SERVER] name and address:" << endl;
winLog << "     ==> the given address is " << serverIPAddress << endl;

myHostInfo serverInfo(serverIPAddress,ADDRESS);
string serverName = serverInfo.getHostName();
cout << "name: " << serverName << endl;
cout << "address: " << serverIPAddress << endl;
winLog << "     ==> name: " << serverName << endl;
winLog << "     ==> address: " << serverIPAddress << endl;

//create the socket for client
myTcpSocket myClient(PORTNUM);
cout << myClient;
winLog << "client configuation: " << endl;
winLog << myClient;

// connect to the server.
cout   << "connecting to the server [" << serverName << "] ... " << endl;
winLog << "connecting to the server [" << serverName << "] ... " << endl;
myClient.connectToServer(serverIPAddress, ADDRESS);

int recvBytes = 0;
while (1)
{
    // send message to server
    char messageToServer[MAX_MSG_LEN+1];
    memset(messageToServer, 0, sizeof(messageToServer));
    cout << "[SEND] ";
    cin.getline(messageToServer,MAX_MSG_LEN);

    winLog << "[SEND] " << messageToServer << endl;
    myClient.sendMessage(string(messageToServer));

    if ( !string(messageToServer).compare("Quit") || !string(messageToServer).compare("quit") ) 
        break;

    // receive message from server
/*  string messageFromServer = "";
    recvBytes = myClient.receiveMessage(messageFromServer);
    if ( recvBytes == -99 ) break;

    cout   << "[RECV:" << serverName << "]: " << messageFromServer << endl;
    winLog << "[RECV:" << serverName << "]: " << messageFromServer << endl;*/

}

return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with threads programming, I'd suggest allocating a separate thread to handle incoming traffic and another one handling outgoing traffic.

Another option is to use asynchronous sockets.

Answer (score 0):

1.After the client connects to the server `client1`, `client2` and `client3` do not close the connect and wait on `read()`

2.On the server side You might want to look into `pselect` and `&timeout`.

3.After the connection is made store the session_fd's into and array `clientId[3]`

4.Now You can write onto `write(client[0-2], , ...)`

LOGIC--

```
int socks[10] = {... some client sockets...}

while(1)
{
   fd_set readSet, writeSet;
   FD_ZERO(&readSet);
   FD_ZERO(&writeSet);

   int maxSock = -1;
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
     FD_SET(socks[i], &readSet);
     if (socks[i] > maxSock) maxSock = socks[i];

     if (IHaveDataToSendToThisSocket(i))  // implement this function as appropriate to your program
      {
        FD_SET(socks[i], &writeSet);
        if (socks[i] > maxSock) maxSock = socks[i];
      }
}

int ret = select(maxSock+1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
{
  perror("select() failed");
  break;
}

// Do I/O for sockets that are ready
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  if (FD_ISSET(socks[i], &readSet))
  {
     // there is data to read on this socket, so call recv() on it
  }

  if (FD_ISSET(socks[i], &writeSet))
  {
     // this socket has space available to write data to, so call send() on it
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Code Snippet By @Jeremy Friesner :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674491/server-with-multiple-clients-writing-with-select